# why can I not managing to block an IP address in windows 7 firewall?

Tags: windows-7, ping, windows-firewall

I pinged google

> C:\Users\user>ping 216.58.211.164
>
> Pinging 216.58.211.164 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from
>   216.58.211.164: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=128

Now I want to try blocking that IP

So I created a rule..
Here are my profile settings

[image: FW-1]

Below you see the rule I created in an attempt to stop myself being able to ping that IP

[image: FW-2]

And here are screenshots showing the rule

[image: FW-3]

[image: FW-4]

[image: FW-5]

[image: FW-6]

[image: FW-7]

[image: FW-8]

Then  I ping and it isn't blocked

[image]

Notice from the screenshots that I have chosen all protocols so it should include ICMP.

Comment: it seems maybe if you create a rule that blocks all, and then (test it, ping, get general failure) then edit it to block just the IP, then it works.. Though that then gives a question of why it doesn't work when I make a rule from scratch setting the IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible Issues

#### 1. Select Any Local IP Address

Unde Scope (in your last screenshot), change "Local IP Address":

- **From**: "These IP Addresses" (`0.0.0.0`)
- **To** "Any IP Address"

Firewall isn't necessarily "*blocking traffic from B*", it's "*blocking traffic between A and B*".

Where A represents your local IP addresses (since multiple IPs can bind to the same box) and B is the remote address.  The sure fire way to block any traffic between your machine to the remote one is to just block all IPs from your local box.

#### 2. Block all connections by default

Windows by default allows all outgoing connections. You need to:

1. Go to `Advanced settings` of firewall
2. Then, on the right side panel, click `properties`
3. Turn on all tabs (Private/Domain/Public) for `Outbound connections` to `block`.

Be warned that it disables **ALL** outgoing connections, and you need to set up outgoing rules after that for any program you want that allowed to go out.

Comment: -1  Windows by default has outgoing connections as a blacklist and that is fine. I want to allow all except particular ones and I want to add rules for those.  I do not want to disable all outgoing like a whitelist, and I shouldn't need to.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you want now. Then change radio-button on the last of your screenshots `Local IP address` from `These IP addresses: 0.0.0.0` to `Any IP addresses`

Comment: +1 well spotted, I didn't realize the win7 firewall didn't really interpret 0.0.0.0 for local interface as Any. So yeah, changing to Any IP address worked. (or my local ip but better 'any'), works nicely and as I wanted.