# Firewall to block traffic to a specific IP - troubleshoot

Tags: windows, networking, ip, firewall, windows-firewall

There's a very similar question on [Using Windows Firewall to block a specific IP on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1159403/180163) but I'm unable to block just a specific IP address.

I'm curious if there's ever a difference between the IP address returned via a `ping` and the one that I need to enter when setting the scope of the windows firewall rules.

Here's the rule setup:

`Type`: **Outbound Rules**
`Action`: **Block the connection**
`Programs`: **All**
`Protocols`: **Any**
`Advanced > Profiles`: **Domain, Private & Public**
`Scope > Local`: **Any IP Address**
`Scope > Remote`: **Any IP Address**

The above rule blocks pretty much *all* outbound traffic to any IP address

And when I run a ping against the machine I want to block, I get the correct results:

[image]

*However*, I don't want to block *all* IP addresses, I only want to block *that* specific one.  So if I update the rule and just change the scope from *Any* to *These IP addresses*, then the traffic is somehow allowed through:

[image]

For any diagnostic reasons, here's the `ipconfig` from server I want to block:

[image]

This thread on [Why can I not managing to block an IP address in windows 7 firewall?](https://superuser.com/a/945306/180163) seems to suggest changing the value for "Local IP address" to just block "Any IP", but that seems over scoped.

How can I figure out what specific local ip addresses to block?  Or alternatively, why does blocking all local IP address allow remote addresses to be blocked?

Comment: what ports and protocols did you select on that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Local IP` represents a specific IP address on your specific device (the computer you are creating the firewall rule on), *not* the IP address of the remote device. It's possible to assign many local IP addresses in case you need to provide various service on an IP-mapping function. In any case, if you're trying to block all access to the remote IP from your computer then you need to use `any` for the `Local IP` setting.

Comment: ohhhh, so it's like **from** these addresses (local) and **to** these addresses (remote).  Not simply "Block B", but "Block traffic between A and B", where A can be a single IP on your machine or just all IPs that are currently mapped to it. Thank you!

Comment: @KyleMit Exactly